# "Order by " how to set it to order numerically

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have an sql Query which is used to generated information for a table in a form. I want the information to be order by the operation. I have the operations numbered from 1-30 but when I view them in the table it orders them with all the operations beginning with one's together and then two's. I know this is becuase the field is a text feild but is there a way to order them numerically?

[image]

Comment: Those numbers, whatever they represent, should probably be a separate column.

Comment: Just a suggestion as I'm not certain it's a working solution, but how about something along the lines of `Order By Len(col), col` - this is a hack, though, a column of INT would be far better ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way is to create an integer `SortOrder` column, populated with values 1 to N in your desired order and order by it.

Failing that you would need to Order by a computed column based off your `Operation` column right padded to a max item length.

Try something like:

```
SELECT Operation, Element, Time
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CInt(Operation) ASC
```

[**Note**: `CInt()` won't behave as expected if a period is present in the number. CInt(8.6) will round up to 9 !]

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename ORDER BY val(operation)
```

Has to be Non numeric after Sort number

Comment: When I run the Query it orders them correctly but when I view the Query as a subform they revert back to the text sorted way any idea why that is ?

Comment: do you have a Sort applied in the subform?

Comment: Thank you Mitch and matzone !

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you order your result on a column with type string - in that case "5 H..." comes after "12 S..." because the sorting algorithm checks first char first... and only the first chars are the same it moves on to the second char...

to get the sorting right, select die partID in an extra column (as int or number) and order by partID

Answer (score 0):

You could include a new column and order by that, for instance:

```
SELECT Operation, Element, Time, Qty, Mid(Operation, 1, 2) AS Order
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Order ASC
```

Note: This wouldn't scale greatly if the number exceeds 2 digits. You'd have to select the first character to the space character and then order. Something like:

```
SELECT Operation, Element, Time, Qty, Mid(Operation, 1, Instr(Operation, " ")) AS Order
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Order ASC
```

Comment: How if there is '100 Solenoid Assembly' ?